# Cannot install new software

Tags: software-installation, software-center, update-manager, dependencies

Whenever I try to install new software, I get this error message

```
"New software can't be installed, because there is a problem with the software currently installed. Do you want to repair this problem now?"
```

So I check to see what the problem is and I get this

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libpcap0.8: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.5 is installed
libpcap0.8:i386: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.5 is installed
```

I googled and I read somewhere that using the following code would solve the issue. Tbh, It didn't. I've posted the output below. Can somebody help me out?

```
root@Beast:~# sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libpcap0.8:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpcap0.8:i386
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 288 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/108 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,216 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 223584 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpcap0.8_1.5.3-2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libpcap0.8:i386 (1.5.3-2) over (1.4.0-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcap0.8_1.5.3-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/man/man7/pcap-filter.7.gz', which is different from other instances of package libpcap0.8:i386
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcap0.8_1.5.3-2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also, running `sudo apt-get autoremove` gives me the following:

```
root@Beast:~# sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcap0.8 : Breaks: libpcap0.8:i386 (!= 1.5.3-2) but 1.4.0-2 is installed
 libpcap0.8:i386 : Breaks: libpcap0.8 (!= 1.4.0-2) but 1.5.3-2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I fixed the issue. I deleted the contents of the libpcap0.8 folder located at

> /usr/share/doc/libpcap0.8

Then I ran the code `apt-get -f install` and the package installed correctly.

I hope this helps other people having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
rm /usr/share/man/man7/pcap-filter.7.gz
rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcap0.8_1.5.3-2_i386.deb
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcap0.8 : Breaks: libpcap0.8:i386 (!= 1.5.3-2) but 1.4.0-2 is installed
 libpcap0.8:i386 : Breaks: libpcap0.8 (!= 1.4.0-2) but 1.5.3-2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: root@Beast:~# apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcap0.8 : Breaks: libpcap0.8:i386 (!= 1.5.3-2) but 1.4.0-2 is installed
 libpcap0.8:i386 : Breaks: libpcap0.8 (!= 1.4.0-2) but 1.5.3-2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: I have no idea what to do now.